# ggplot editable with powerpoint and/or word

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, ms-word, powerpoint

i'm trying to create a ggplot editable with ppt or word

Here's the code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvg)
library(officer)

##I create a dml object
anyplot = dml(code = barplot(1:5, col = 2:6), bg = "wheat")

## add slide
doc <- read_pptx()

##specify object and location of object
doc <- add_slide(doc, "Title and Content", "Office Theme")
doc <- ph_with.dml(doc, anyplot, location = ph_location_fullsize())

## print it in pptx
print(doc, target = 'plot.pptx')
```

But I keep getting *could not find function "ph_with.dml"*

note: I understand `ph_with.dml` is the new version of `ph_with_vg` (which cannot be find either)

Any suggestion or different approach would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried with `ph_with(doc, ..)`?

Comment: thanks @stefan. I did with my original plot and wasn't working but with this barplot works perfecty! I'm gonna try with my plot and let you know.